# Can we access App Information from the AppStore in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, app-store

Here is my requirement ,

1. Obtaining the list of apps from the AppStore, This contains basic information of the app.
2. Provide ratings to these app from my app.

Is there an API from Apple where i can achieve the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this what the "App store" app is doing by default? I am not sure Apple is going to approve that if you manage to do something like that. Apple certainly wont want a duplicate....

Comment: I agree with you, i was thinking of having some customization to what the app store already does, i think that there are no APIs for this. But if there is please let me know.

Comment: I am not sure there is and I dont think it will be available until Apple thinks its time they allow people to do things that only they can do right now

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot. Apple **forbids** you from scraping their sites in Apps on the App Store.

From Apple's "Review Guidelines" - section 12

http://images.worldofapple.com/appstoreguidelines_9910.pdf

- Scraping and aggregation

  - Applications that scrape any information from Apple sites (for example from apple.com, iTunes Store, App Store, iTunes Connect, Apple Developer Programs, etc) or create rankings using content from Apple sites and services will be rejected
  - Applications may use approved Apple RSS feeds such as the iTunes Store RSS feed
  - Apps that are simply web clippings, content aggregators, or a collection of links, may be
    rejected